# The PersonGroup - Create Operation under Face API - V1.0 API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have tried to use the Face API with Azure, and have tied the API call to a subscription with both the F0 and S1 pricing tier, but I keep getting this error :(

```
"The PersonGroup - Create Operation under Face API - V1.0 API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier ComputerVision"
```

I have tried with POSTMAN and Microsoft Flow. Does anyone know what tier I in fact have to use in order to actually create a person group? If I can't do this step, I can't do anything else as it all relies on having a group to attribute a person to.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a `Face API` resource key for the call? by look of the error message you're using a `Computer Vision API` key - not the same service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MSLEARN myself and finally found the solution:
despite the statement from MS that an overarching CognitiveService resource group can be used, it MUST be a Face instance. Then it's working, and regardless of the pricing tier (F0 or S0).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while going through some Microsoft Learn material. I was trying to use a previously provisioned Cognitive Services resource. I had resource #1 set to S0 pricing tier. But it would not work. So I provisioned another Cognitive Services resource at the S0 pricing tier and the exercise worked. ?? Go figure.

This all occured while I was trying to run Python Jupiter Notebooks.